# How can I scan for virus in Azure App Service when uploading a file using MVC not using a third pary API with C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

How can I scan for virus in Azure App Service (Azure Web Sites) when uploading a file using MVC not using a third pary API such as VirusTotal with C#?

Is it possible to run Windows Defender?

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

CS example code, is it possible to run mpcmdrun.exe?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file) {

  if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
    file.SaveAs(path);

    //Scan for Virus
    var virusScanner = new VirusScanner()
    var results = virusScanner.Scan(path);
    if(results.Viruses.Any())
    {
        File.Delete(path);
    }
  }

  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: You want to search for viruses without using a third party API?

Comment: Either scan for viruses using an external tool, or don't scan for viruses. But doing it yourself won't happen and/or won't work

Comment: Well I dont want to use API were I need to upload the file to another third part? I rather have a external tool in a hosted environment if that is possible but I wont be able to host any application inside the app service? I wonder if it possible to call windows defender from the app service.

Comment: I'm not sure within azure app service you are allowed to use windows defender

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to run Windows Defender?

The Windows Defender ATP is for Windows Server , it doesn't support Azure Web.

For now, there is no native virus scanning / anti-malware feature on Websites. However you could implement it with third party API like [ClamAV](https://github.com/tekmaven/nClam) or the extension in Azure App Service named with Tinfoil Security.

There are two ways to integrate it to you app, first you could refer to this [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/web-vulnerability-scanning-for-azure-app-service-powered-by-tinfoil-security/) ,I tried this way however It show "Failed to purchase". So maybe you could try another way. Under **Development Tools** in your App choose **Extensions** , click Add button then Choose Extension, on the list there is a **Tinfoil Security** , that's what we need. I tried this way, it could be integrated to my App.

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: after following your 2nd option, tinfoil, what should i do with this extension, I mean if I upload some suspected file through application, does this extension will ask me or I mean what will be the use or purpose of this extension